# adding classes (serially numbered) to each DIV on page automatically via javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

i'm running a contact-form-plugin on my wordpress installation. everything works fine but i want to style my form a little bit more. to do it like this i have to style some DIVs (which the plugin is processing) in a different way. the problem is: all DIV-containers have no IDs or classes! everything is processed by the plugin and my PHP-skills are like zero so i have to deal with this "naked" DIVs ;-)

the question is: is it possible to add serially numbered classes to each DIV on the current site via javascript?

thanks so far and i hope you get waht i mean (sorry for that shitty english)!

Comment: Why you want to add serial numbered class you can do that using same class...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yet another way, passing a callback to [`.attr` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$('div').attr('class', function(i) {
    return 'someClass' + i;
});
```

Though you could also use this for IDs instead, since each class will be unique.

**Note** that you don't have to use IDs or classes to select elements, there are a number of [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors) and [traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) methods with which you can get a reference to the elements you want.

---

To prevent overriding existing classes, either select only the elements with no class or somehow narrow down the selection of `div`s to only those you want:

```
$('div:not([class])')
```

or use [`.addClass` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) instead of `.attr`:

```
$('div').addClass(function(i) {
    return 'someClass' + i;
});
```

Comment: +1 as you can specify a cless for the divs you want to style and not *every* div in the DOM!

Comment: thanks for the wuick answer.. i tried it (i putted this javascript code to my header)... there where no DIVs added automatically, right? how do i style them now? sorry for all the dumb questions...

Comment: Well, you only asked for how to add classes... for styling use CSS. I don't know if adding classes programatically makes it any easier to style it, I thought you already knew how to do and that's why you asked. Maybe you should have asked for how to style elements without any classes or IDs?

Comment: to be more specicifc: i found a website which uses the same contact form like mine: http://greten-steuerberatung.de/kontakt/ if you look at the code, the DIVs around the input/labels of the form do not have any classes or IDs... but i need to style every DIV on its owen...

Comment: and i tried your solution but no IDs oder classes where added?!? waht have i done wrong?

Comment: Maybe you execute the code before any `div`s exist. I don't know how much experience you have with jQuery, I recommend to read the tutorial: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery.

Comment: ok, i got it.. it works now.. but: it overwrites all the other classes (of the DIVs which already have one)?!?! is there a way to ADD them?

Comment: [The answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971416/adding-classes-via-javascript-to-each-div-without-overwriting-exisiting-classes), why did you pick `attr` and not `addClass`?

Comment: @gdoron: Many reasons: Influenced by other answers, OP said `div`s don't have a classes (-> lack of information), wanted to use a callback and return the new value. But I saw that `addClass` accepts a callback too...

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/Vztfm/)**

```
$('div').each(function(i, item){
    $(this).attr('class', "YourClass" + i); //You can replace i with some other variable if required and increment it.
});
```

Comment: While it might not matter at this scale, jQuery's `.each` is one of the slower implementations.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var className = "myClass";
for( var i = 0, max = divs.length; i< max; i++ ){
 divs[i].setAttribute("class",className + i.toString());
}
```

Comment: except the `"i"` would be a static letter i, you probably mean to do this without the quotes, and you're imagining you're forcing a cast to string by doing this. `""+i` would force casting to a string, but you're already adding it to a string, so it coerces natively.

Comment: @jcolebrand you've got the rep to fix his answer.

Comment: @jcolebrand - Yes, this was done before I left for work so it was a little hurried. edited to fix.

Comment: @Mathletics sure, but I wanted to make sure Travis was on the same page, and don't recall that editing an answer for someone over 6k notifies them ... sometimes we all make silly mistakes, and sometimes we have other reasons (such as, we think we're doing the right thing)