# adding classes via javascript to each DIV without overwriting exisiting classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [adding classes (serially numbered) to each DIV on page automatically via javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960028/adding-classes-serially-numbered-to-each-div-on-page-automatically-via-javascr)

I want to add a class which "numbers" all the `<div>`s, problem is, is that it overrides the existing classes.

```
$('div').attr('class', function(i) {
    return 'someClass' + i;
});
```

Comment: I edited the question, please make the question short and with relevant data only. Thanks!

Comment: IMHO, this does not deserve to be a new question. You asked for clarification on your previous question, but I cannot do anything when I'm asleep ;) Stackoverflow is amazing in that it provides help very quickly, but that does not mean that you are entitled to quick answers and sometimes you have to be patient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('div').each(function(i){
    $(this).addClass('class' + i);
});
```

Or:

```
$('div').addClass(function(i){
    return "class" + i;
});
```

Comment: yeah, thats exactly what i wanted.. thanks dude!

Comment: and by the way: is it possible to just let it add the classes within a contact form (<form></form)?

Comment: @BrayazZayarb. Do you mean this: `$('form div').each(function(i){
    $(this).addClass('class' + i);
});`

Comment: yeah, thanks... it's that easy ;-)

Answer (score 0):

check here ,

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

```
$("p").addClass("myClass yourClass");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').each(function(i, item){
    $(this).addClass("someClass" + i);
});
```

This will add to the existing classes

Answer (score 0):

This will add the index to the existing class value.

```
$(function(){
$('div').attr('class', function(i, val) {
      return val + i;
});
});
```